# Groovy .collect with number of elements limit

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Is there a way to use the groovy `.collect` method, but only up to a certain index in the source array?

For example if your source iterator was 1 million long and your limit was 100, you would end up with an array of 100 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using any data structure that implements `java.util.List` you can do a `collection.subList(0, 100)` on it. Where 0 is the start index and 100 is the end. After that you'd pass the new collection into `collect()`.

Here is an example using an object that extends `java.util.Iterator`:

```
public class LimitIterator implements Iterator, Iterable {
   private it
   private limit
   private count

   LimitIterator(Iterator it, int limit) {
      limit = limit;
      count = 0;
      it = it
   }

   boolean hasNext(){
      return (count >= limit) ? false : it.hasNext()
   }

   Object next() {
      if (!hasNext()) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException()

      count++
      return it.next()
   }

   Iterator iterator(){
      return this;
   }

   void remove(){
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove() not supported")
   }

}

// Create a range from 1 to 10000
// and an empty list.
def list = 1..10000
def shortList = []

// Ensure that everything is as expected
assert list instanceof java.util.List
assert list.iterator() instanceof java.util.Iterator
assert list.size() == 10000
assert shortList instanceof java.util.List

// Grab the first 100 elements out of the lists iterator object.
for (i in new LimitIterator(list.iterator(), 100)) {
    shortlist.add(i);
}
assert shortlist.size() == 100
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a list

Comment: @Matt you can probably call `toList()` or `as List` to convert it to a List

Comment: I worry that may ultimately read the entire iterator into memory

Comment: @Matt how is the array currently being stored?

Comment: @icirellik It isn't an array, its 'something' that implements iteratable. While iterating over the contents, it may issue a lookup over the network (the contents aren't necessarily in memory) to grab the next chunk of items.

Comment: @Matt You could always create a wrapper that implements iterator and take a max size.

Comment: @icirellik thats a great idea actually. I think I will go with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Since Groovy 1.8.1 you can also do

```
list.take(100).collect { ... }
```

where take will return the first 100 elements from the list.

Comment: Is *take* lazy like in Clojure, or strict?

Comment: Without having read the code I presume take(...) is strict. Lazy is great in a language like Clojure where the data structures are immutable, less so in Groovy where almost everything is mutable. Lazy can still be great, but does not make sense as a default.

Comment: This is an operation on list and therefore the entire list will be in memory so it will be strict not lazy like in clojure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a range of indices to obtain a sublist, and then apply `collect` to the sublist.

```
def result = list[0..100].collect { ... }
```